# Max and min width for html table not working in CSS

Tags: html, css

I had defined the min-width and max-width in CSS, nothing happens. i also tried define it like this, `<td style="min-width: 30px; max-width: 50px;`> still nothing. so how to make it work for max and min-width? I want the long text from the database to automatically go down to next line when it reaches to the maximum size of the cell.

```css
table,tr,td,th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: normal;
  
}

table tr td:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: red;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 140%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

table td {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div name="tables">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>No Seq</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Person in Charge</th>
      <th>Project Title</th>
      <th>Objectives</th>
      <th>How To Do</th>
      <th>Activities</th>
      <th>Project Started</th>
      <th>Project Completed</th>
      <th>Target Cost Saving(RM)/Year</th>
      <th>Cost Saving After Justification</th>
      <th>Cost Saving Monthly</th>
    </tr>
    
   <tr id="row1">
      <td> <?php echo $id;?></td>
      <td id="department_row1"> <?php echo $department;?></td>
      <td id="pic_row1"> <?php echo $person_in_charge;?></td>
      <td id="protitle_row1"> <?php echo $project_title;?></td>
      <td id="objective_row1"> <?php echo $objective;?></td>
      <td id="howtodo_row1"><?php echo $how_to_do;?></td>
      <td id="activities_row1"> <?php echo $activities;?></td>
      <td id="prostart_row1"> <?php echo $project_started;?></td>
      <td id="procompl_row1"> <?php echo $project_completed;?></td>
      <td id="targetcost_row1"> <?php echo $target_cost_saving;?></td>
      <td id="costafter_row1"> <?php echo $costsaving_afterjustification;?></td>
      <td id="costmonthly_row1"> <?php echo $costsaving_monthly;?></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: I think your problem lies in `width: 140%;` :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables use width and height properties as rough hints rather than absolute rules.
If you really want the content in a table cell to not exceed a certain width, the only foolproof way is to add more markup. Put a div in the cell that you assign the properties such as `max-width` to.

Another problem in your particular example is the combination of `table-layout:fixed` combined with no sizes at all for the first row. That means the browser will assign widths to the columns based on only the first row and will totally ignore any attempts at sizing later on. I've commented out the table-layout property.

```css
table, tr, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: normal;
}

table tr td:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

table {
  /*table-layout: fixed;
  width: 140%;*/
  margin-left: 20px;
}

th > div, td > div {
  max-width: 100px;
  min-width: 50px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div name="tables">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th><div>No Seq</div></th>
      <th><div>Department</div></th>
      <th><div>Person in Charge</div></th>
      <th><div>Project Title</div></th>
      <th><div>Objectives</div></th>
      <th><div>How To Do</div></th>
      <th><div>Activities</div></th>
      <th><div>Project Started</div></th>
      <th><div>Project Completed</div></th>
      <th><div>Target Cost Saving(RM)/Year</div></th>
      <th><div>Cost Saving After Justification</div></th>
      <th><div>Cost Saving Monthly</div></th>
    </tr>

    <tr id="row1">
      <td><div> 1</div></td>
      <td id="department_row1"><div> some text </div></td>
      <td id="pic_row1"><div> some rather long text </div></td>
      <td id="protitle_row1"><div> text </div></td>
      <td id="objective_row1"><div> text </div></td>
      <td id="howtodo_row1"><div> text </div></td>
      <td id="activities_row1"><div> text </div></td>
      <td id="prostart_row1"><div> text </div></td>
      <td id="procompl_row1"><div> text </div></td>
      <td id="targetcost_row1"><div> text </div></td>
      <td id="costafter_row1"><div> text </div></td>
      <td id="costmonthly_row1"><div> text </div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah i did this like you told me and it works fine! thankyou so much :)

Answer (score 1):

If you insert word-break : break-all; in table this will break the word when the word goes past the divs width.

```css
table,tr,td,th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: normal;      
}

table tr td:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 140%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  word-break : break-all;
}

table td {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div name="tables">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>No Seq</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Person in Charge</th>
      <th>Project Title</th>
      <th>Objectives</th>
      <th>How To Do</th>
      <th>Activities</th>
      <th>Project Started</th>
      <th>Project Completed</th>
      <th>Target Cost Saving(RM)/Year</th>
      <th>Cost Saving After Justification</th>
      <th>Cost Saving Monthly</th>
    </tr>
    
   <tr id="row1">
      <td> <?php echo $id;?></td>
      <td id="department_row1"> <?php echo $department;?></td>
      <td id="pic_row1"> <?php echo $person_in_charge;?></td>
      <td id="protitle_row1"> <?php echo $project_title;?></td>
      <td id="objective_row1"> <?php echo $objective;?></td>
      <td id="howtodo_row1"><?php echo $how_to_do;?></td>
      <td id="activities_row1"> <?php echo $activities;?></td>
      <td id="prostart_row1"> <?php echo $project_started;?></td>
      <td id="procompl_row1"> <?php echo $project_completed;?></td>
      <td id="targetcost_row1"> <?php echo $target_cost_saving;?></td>
      <td id="costafter_row1"> <?php echo $costsaving_afterjustification;?></td>
      <td id="costmonthly_row1"> <?php echo $costsaving_monthly;?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After min-width and max-width use **display:inline-block or display:block;** optional one **overflow:hidden;**

```
table td {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-width: 50px;
  display:block;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: it didnt work in table td. i've added display:inline-block in table but it only affect for max-width only. if i adjusted the min-width, nothing happened. but thankyou anyway ive already found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to squeeze your table to fit on screens by force, allow it to look decent and to scroll when there's not enough space. Wrap it inside an element with `overflow-x:auto;`:

```css
.tables {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
table,tr,td,th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table tr td:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: red;
}

table {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

th,td {
  min-width: 50px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tables">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>No Seq</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Person in Charge</th>
      <th>Project Title</th>
      <th>Objectives</th>
      <th>How To Do</th>
      <th>Activities</th>
      <th>Project Started</th>
      <th>Project Completed</th>
      <th>Target Cost Saving(RM)/Year</th>
      <th>Cost Saving After Justification</th>
      <th>Cost Saving Monthly</th>
    </tr>
    
   <tr id="row1">
      <td> <?php echo $id;?></td>
      <td id="department_row1"> <?php echo $department;?></td>
      <td id="pic_row1"> <?php echo $person_in_charge;?></td>
      <td id="protitle_row1"> <?php echo $project_title;?></td>
      <td id="objective_row1"> <?php echo $objective;?></td>
      <td id="howtodo_row1"><?php echo $how_to_do;?></td>
      <td id="activities_row1"> <?php echo $activities;?></td>
      <td id="prostart_row1"> <?php echo $project_started;?></td>
      <td id="procompl_row1"> <?php echo $project_completed;?></td>
      <td id="targetcost_row1"> <?php echo $target_cost_saving;?></td>
      <td id="costafter_row1"> <?php echo $costsaving_afterjustification;?></td>
      <td id="costmonthly_row1"> <?php echo $costsaving_monthly;?></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
```

You should also remove `width: 140%` from your table.

Also note `name` attribute on `<div>`s is not valid HTML. It's only used on form elements and its purpose is to provide a mechanism for indexing data over GET and POST requests.

Comment: yeah that is also the thing that i'm working on. To make a scrollable table by adding `.tables { overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto; }` in my css but it didnt work on my table..

Comment: @lishayaacob: that's probably because your `<div>` still has `name="tables"` instead of `class="tables"`. I assume you haven't read my answer till the end and you haven't payed attention to markup.